# How to provide reference to the secret namespace in ClusterIssuer?

Tags: kubernetes, ca, kubernetes-secrets, cert-manager

I have a ClusterIssuer that is expecting `secretName`, I see in the `ClusterIssuer` `spec`, I can specify the `secretName`:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: postgres-operator-ca-certificate-cluster-issuer
spec:
  ca:
    secretName: postgres-operator-ca-certificate     # <---- Here
```

but how to provide the reference to the secret namespace? This secret is created using `Certificate`:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: postgres-operator-self-signed-ca-certificate
  namespace: postgres                 # <---- This namespace can not be changed to cert-manager
spec:
  isCA: true
  commonName: postgres-operator-ca-certificate
  secretName: postgres-operator-ca-certificate
  issuerRef:
    name: postgres-operator-selfsigned-clusterissuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

As this is `namespaced` is the suggestion is to use `Issuer` instead of `ClusterIssuer`? Does `ClusterIssuer` by default look in the `cert-manager` namespace?

Comment: If I use `Issuer` that will solve the issue, but is there a way to use `ClusterIssuer` instead

Comment: in my case we are using reflector, feel free to take a look here: https://github.com/emberstack/kubernetes-reflector/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 5):

Typically it will look for the secret in the namespace `cert-manager` by default. Which namespace it looks in can be changed by your cert-manager installation by using the `--cluster-resource-namespace` argument, but not by individual ClusterIssuer.

From the documentation:

> If the referent is a cluster-scoped resource (e.g. a ClusterIssuer),
> the reference instead refers to the resource with the given name in
> the configured ‘cluster resource namespace’, which is set as a flag on
> the controller component (and defaults to the namespace that
> cert-manager runs in).

https://cert-manager.io/docs/reference/api-docs/#meta.cert-manager.io/v1.LocalObjectReference

Comment: Thanks! That's a feasible solution, but that will make cert-manager not reusable by other services if they are on a different namespace. +1 but can not accept as an answer.

Comment: @Vishrant i didn't offer a solution, i answered your question about ClusterIssuers, secrets, and namespaces. What question/problem are you looking for an answer to?

Comment: The `Certificate` is a namespaced object, the secret will get created in the same ns where the Certificate has been created, the `ClusterIssuer` has no namespace, but it expects the secrets to be in `cert-manager`, which is contradictory. There should be a way in the ClusterIssuer to specify the ns for the secret that it's trying to sign. The question is there is a way to let ClusterIssuer object know where to look for a secret without changing the Certificate ns or specifying `cluster-resource-namespace` (cluster-resource-namespace will add limitation for other applications)

Comment: the answer to that is no. there is no way to do that. in my experience, people turn to an operator to copy/sync secrets among different namespaces to solve the overall problem you have. there are multiple tools that do this.

Comment: having another operator to achieve it will be over-engineering. I think the changes should be made in the cert-manager injector itself. But thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: +1 for providing the correct answer. It's weird to see someone arguing with you because they don't *like* the answer.